# non-const passed to a function with parameter as const type

Tags: c++

In this code:

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    void fun(const int *val)
    {
        std::cout<<"hello world\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    class A obj;
    int i=9;
    obj.fun(&i); 
    return 0;
}
```

On passing a non-constant address to a pointer to `const`, how does a compiler upgrades the address passed to a `const` type?

As per C++ Primer

> initializing a `const` reference to a non-const object requires a conversion.

Comment: You can pass a non-const object to a function requiring a const one, but not vice versa

Comment: @CoryKramer That's the part I am trying to understand to get it's underlying mechanism. I get it that a non-const object will not have its values changed by a const parameter.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus There's no mechanism. It just a rule of the language. All the compiler is doing is applying the rules, it's not changing anything.

Comment: Think of `const` here as a promise that the value at `val` will not be changed as a result of `fun`. The compiler will then enforce the promise. Whether or not the source argument is constant or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @john I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: @user4581301 That part I understand, the question is about the underlying conversion.

Comment: The 'conversion' is conceptual, it's a conversion of the *type* of the pointer. The value of pointer is not getting changed. Put another way, this conversion will generate no code at all in the compiled program.